# Java ArrayList search element and input into Jlist

Tags: java, list, jlist

I want to program a search function of the arraylist . Example I search for Simon, name that contains Simon should show up in the Jlist as shown below. The part I couldnt figure is what is the condition should I check for and what should I be adding.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Main

```
 public static ArrayList al = new ArrayList();     
    

    al.add("Alica Wonderland");
    al.add("Bob Jr");
    al.add("Simon Tay");
    al.add("Simon Corbell");
    al.add("Simon Flyman");
    al.add("Simon Jr");
    al.add("David Copper");
```

### Button Action

```
private void btnSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   String value = txtSearch.getText();
    
    listModel = new DefaultListModel();  
    JList ListAll =  new JList(listModel);
    
    if(al.contains(value)){
        listModel.addElement(?Name that contains Simon?);
    }
     ListAll.setModel(listModel);  
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++)
    if(al.get(i).contains(value))
        listModel.addElement(al.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over `ArrayList` elements:

```
for (Object s : al) {
    if (((String)s).contains("Simon"))
        listModel.addElement(s);
}
```

**PS:** You can avoid cast stuff by defining a type for `ArrayList`:

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: the performance of iterate over 5000 entries will it be affected?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this:

```
String name = "Simon";
for(int k = 0; k = yourArraylist.size() - 1; k++) {

    if(yourArraylist.get(k).equals(name)) {.

        your_Jlist.add(name);
        //...

    }

}
```

Comment: That's not the way of comparing `String`s.

Comment: You should use equals() or equalsIgnoreCase() methods to compare String objects in java

Comment: This is one of the ways. Of course you can use equals() method, but the answer is correct. I just changed it...